# Why to double check the singleton instantiation

Tags: java, singleton, double-checked-locking

In [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/05/double-checked-locking-on-singleton-in-java.html) link i found the singleton instantiation as below:

```
public static Singleton getInstanceDC() {
        if (_instance == null) {                // Single Checked (1)
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (_instance == null) {        // Double checked
                    _instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return _instance;
}
```

I am not getting the point of single check ie (1) . Whats its use here any way the single thread will be checking the instance inside synchronized block , so what is point of using the first check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that in a multithreaded environment two threads can access your singleton.
Here is what can happen without a double check.

First thread enters `getInstanceDC()`; `_instance` is `null` so it enters the `if` block.
Second thread enters `getInstanceDC()`; `_instance` is `null` so it enters the `if` block.
First thread creates a new instance.
Second thread creates a new instance.

The double check in a synchronized block solves this problem.

So why not synchronize the whole method? The answer is for performance reasons.

Comment: but the second check is under synchronized block so only one thread will enter there at a time (since it has a  Class class object lock), and by the time it comes out of the sync block the instance is created, so first check stays useless, isnt it so?

Comment: The first check is out of synchronized block. Most of the times the check will say that _instance is already existent (not null). This check is done without synchronization, so is faster.

Comment: ohh.got it now..it will avoid needless stay in synchronized block..:)